# One Signal push notification with customized icon from database

Tags: push-notification, onesignal, symfony-2.8

I want customize my one signal push notification icon. I mean I want import it from my database. I could set the title like code below, but still not founding a way to change the icon from my database.

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
  OneSignal.setDefaultTitle("My Title");
});
```